# Preferred way for spawning objects after time delay

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

What would be better/preferred way for spawning objects continuously in the scene ? This:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:
      [SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnObject)
                         onTarget:self],
        [SKAction waitForDuration:0.1]]]]];
```

Or to use custom method eg. updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate: to check how much time passed from the last update and do spawning based on that?

Comment: Both work perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi Steffen. I was concerned about how these methods react when scene or view is paused etc, because I don't want objects get spawned while game is paused, but if you say that's everything is ok, I have a few good reasons to believe you :) Thanks!

Comment: well, there's one difference: if I remember correctly, when the scene is paused it will still run its update: etc methods but not actions.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D That is true... When scene is paused, all actions are stopped and update method was running, I just tested it.

Comment: if you pause your SKScene file, then update will not stop.  However, if you pause SKView, the update loop WILL stop.  you can access SKView from your GameViewController, or you can access it from didMoveToView in your SKScene